# Javascript - How to convert an array indexed by tuples to a multidimensional array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, tuples, opl

I have an array -  X[(i,j,l)] that is indexed by tuples of 3 indexes, the indexes of i and j run from 1 to n, and the index of l runs from 1 to "layers".  My array is binary - the value of each element is 0 or 1.

I got this array as a result of running an optimization problem in opl - in CPLEX.

I would like to read the values of X as a multidimensional array X[i][j][l] using the execution code in javascript in the model window.

This is what I tried:

```
var ofile_varx = new IloOplOutputFile("initial_varx.csv");
ofile_varx.writeln(x);

var x_arr=new Array (n);
for (var i=0; i<n; i++) {
    x_arr[i]=new Array (n);
    for (var j=0; j<n; j++) {
        x_arr[i][j]=new Array (layers);
    }
}           
for (var tup in ijl) {
    x_arr[tup.i][tup.j][tup.l]=x[tup];
}
```

I got an error from the last line that says that it cannot assign a property "null" to the array.

Any idea of how to get to my requested array x_arr?

Thank you!

Comment: Please share the input format samples and expected output for the same.

Comment: `ofile_varx.writeln(x);` what is `x`, I see no x so why does that line exist?  What is `n`?  is `typeof n === "undefined"`?  You reference `X[i][j][l]` in your discourse but are we to assume `X` is `x_arr`?  Where in `(var tup in ijl)` is  `ijl` defined?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Perhaps start here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and then revise your question to include a more complete example.

Comment: X was given (a binary array that its items can be reached only by index that is of values <ijl>).   I think I managed to type x_arr to csv now.  My problem was the indexes : x_arr[tup.i-1][tup.j-1][tup.l-1].  Although the result cannot be easily printed or exported like in python, i got the result I wanted.  Thank you!

Comment: ijl is defined of course in opl. I wanted to create x_arr out of X.  I think I managed.

Answer (score 0):

```
tuple t
{
 int i;
 int j;
 int l;
}

int n=2;
int layers=3;
{t} ijl={<1,2,3>,<1,2,1>};

dvar int x[ijl];
subject to
{
forall(i in ijl) x[i]==i.i;
}


execute
{
var x_arr=new Array (n);
for (var i=0; i<=n; i++) {
    x_arr[i]=new Array (n);
    for (var j=0; j<=n; j++) {
        x_arr[i][j]=new Array (layers);
    }
}           
for (var tup in ijl) {
    x_arr[tup.i][tup.j][tup.l]=x[tup].solutionValue;
}
}
```

works fine.